# Parallel test execution with SpecFlow, xUnit and Headless Chrome

Tags: c#, selenium, specflow, xunit, google-chrome-headless

I want to run some SpecFlow scenario tests in headless Chrome in parallel. I am using SpecFlow/xUnit and using Selenium to start up headless Chrome in my `BeforeScenario` method like this:

```
public class FeatureProperties : BaseSteps
{
    private static Object myLockObj = new Object();
    private static readonly Random Randomiser = new Random();

    private IObjectContainer Container { get; set; }

    public FeatureProperties(PageContext _context, IObjectContainer _container) : base(_context)
    {
        Container = _container;
    }

    [BeforeScenario]
    public void BeforeScenario()
    {
        var options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.AddArguments("--incognito", "--headless", "--window-size=1920,1080", "--disable-gpu", "--no-sandbox");

        options.AddArguments("--proxy-server='direct://'");
        options.AddArguments("--proxy-bypass-list=*");

        lock (myLockObj)
        {
            var rnd = Randomiser.Next(29700, 29900);
            Console.WriteLine("Randomised: " + rnd);
            var svc = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
            svc.Port = rnd;
            svc.Start();
            Context.Driver = new ChromeDriver(svc, options);
        }
    }
```

I'm seeing this in the command line when I execute `xunit.console.exe`:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.37.543627 (63642262d9fb93fb4ab52398be4286d844092a5e) on port 29780
Only local connections are allowed.
Starting ChromeDriver 2.37.543627 (63642262d9fb93fb4ab52398be4286d844092a5e) on port 29780
Only local connections are allowed.
[1522066314.720][SEVERE]: bind() returned an error: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. (0x2740)
```

I understand (?) that Chrome wants a different port to start up on, but I'm not sure how to configure that. Adding this did not help:

```
svc.Port = new System.Random().Next(29700, 29900);
```

For reference, here are the relevant parts of my packages.config:

```
<packages>
  <package id="Selenium.Support" version="3.11.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Selenium.WebDriver" version="3.11.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver" version="2.37.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="SpecFlow" version="2.3.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="SpecFlow.xUnit" version="2.3.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="SpecFlow.xUnitAdapter" version="1.1.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="xunit" version="2.3.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="xunit.abstractions" version="2.0.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="xunit.analyzers" version="0.8.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="xunit.assert" version="2.3.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="xunit.core" version="2.3.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="xunit.extensibility.core" version="2.3.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="xunit.extensibility.execution" version="2.3.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="xunit.runner.visualstudio" version="2.3.1" targetFramework="net461" developmentDependency="true" />
</packages>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using one shared `Random` variable. `new System.Random()` initializes the Pseudo random number generator with the current time. In case of parallel execution, this can very well be the same time and `Next` will result in the same number for all calls.

Comment: Just added the randomiser code for the port number in my original post. I am getting the exact same result. There are two scenarios and I'm seeing two instances of chrome attempting to start with the same port number on each. Am I setting the wrote option/property? What would the right one be?

Comment: @MattW: How many xunit.console.exe instances are being started? Multiple or a single one?

Comment: Try surrounding the `svc.Port = ...` line with a `lock` and see if that helps

Comment: No change. Exactly the same output. Seeing this, twice: Starting ChromeDriver 2.37.543627 (63642262d9fb93fb4ab52398be4286d844092a5e) on port 29810

Comment: OK, so the code you showed executes only once. It looks like you are re-using the `driver` variable. You need to show more code. What are you doing with the `driver` variable? How is the code called that you show?

Comment: I have just posted a fuller set of code. The webdriver is being instantiated in the BeforeScenario which should execute once for each test, so twice per test run. With the lock I would expect a unique port number for each instance of the driver.

Comment: The driver is stored in an instance of PageContext which is injected into the constructor by SpecFlow, so that should be unique per scenario, too.

Comment: Yes, I would expect it to be unique as well which tells me that the code is executed only once. You should be able to verify that by putting a Console.WriteLine(something) into the code block.

Comment: Also, in SpecFlow you have scenarios, features and steps. Maybe your tests are both in the same scenario?

Comment: They are two scenarios in the same feature.

Comment: Are you saying that for parallel browser testing the scenarios would each have to be in a separate feature file? That sort of defeats the purpose.

Comment: @MattW: No, I am not saying this. Your problem seems to be that you are NOT using two different instances of the `ChromeDriver` class but only a single one. I am simply trying to give you some hints what the reason could be.

Comment: Ok. I've updated the code snippet with as much as I can. Debugging through I can see that BeforeScenario() gets called twice and both times the Context.Driver is null on entry. I am seeing 'Starting ChromeDriver 2.37.543627 on port 29897' twice, each with a different port number. I only have the 'new ChromeDriver' statement on that one line in the entire solution and it only executes twice - once for each scenario, each uniquely.

Comment: Well, turns out it was the use of 'svc.Start();' which was kicking off an instance of Chrome, which, of course, caused the new ChromeDriver' to be problematic. I'm guessing you knew that ;) Thank you for your help.